# Can't access @Field global variable

Tags: java, groovy

I have these global variable inside my Groovy script

```
@Field ZonedDateTime currentDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))

@Field DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

But I can't seem to access it inside the class in my script :(

```
class SmsMessageDeliveryPartResult {
    String dateSent
    String dateDeliveryReceiptReceived

    DeliveryResult() {
        this.dateSent = currentDateTime.format(formatter)
        this.dateDeliveryReceiptReceived = currentDateTime.format(formatter)
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentDateTime for class:
```

Comment: Did you `import groovy.transform.Field` ?

Comment: Hi sir. yes i did. :( right now, i just added it as a local field to my class.